# Trying to get file from input returns Object Error in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I already searched for the specific error but couldn't really come up with a lot of useful information. The code in question returning the error is below.

### JS:

```
var files = document.getElementById("file").files;
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
    document.getElementById("filename").value = files[i].name;
    document.getElementById("filename").setAttribute('value', files[i].name);
    document.getElementById("filename") = document.getElementById("filename");
```

### HTML:

```
    <form action="../interface/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <span class="btn btn-default btn-file btn-lg btn-block">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file fileinput-exists"></i> Browse File <input type="file" id="file" onchange="getfile()" name="file" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet">
          <input id="filename" type="text" class="btn" value="No file choosen" disabled="true">
      </span>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">
    </form>
```

The goal is to display the name of the selected file in the "filename" input.

For some reason this returns me the following error in IE8

### ERROR / IE8:

> ```
> Message: 'length' is Null or not an Object
> Line: 4
> Character: 18
> Code: 0
> URI: http://localhost/assets/js/filechooser.js
> ```

### Fix

```
function getfile(evt)
{
  var filename = evt.value;
  filename = filename.split('\\').pop();
  document.getElementById("filename").value = filename;
}
```

Comment: Where's your HTML? Have you attempted to [debug your JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)

Comment: added html, yes i did debug the js (code on the bottom is the error message from IE)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you only have one single element returned by `document.getElementById("file").files`, `file` doesn't have `length`. Protect for this special case, and also for all cases that return nothing.

**EDIT:**

since you clarified that you always have one `file` element, the following may work for you:

```
<form action="../interface/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <span class="btn btn-default btn-file btn-lg btn-block">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file fileinput-exists"></i> Browse File <input type="file" id="file" onchange="getfile(this)" name="file" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet">
          <input id="filename" type="text" class="btn" value="No file choosen" disabled="true">
      </span>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">
</form>


<script language="javascript">
function getfile(evt)
{
  alert(evt.value);
  document.getElementById("filename").value = evt.value;
}
</script>
```

Please note the `onchange="getfile(this)"` edit I made to your HTML.

Comment: In my specific use-case there is always a single element returned.
Can you give me an example how you'd alter the code?

Comment: @user3513936 `Message: 'length' is Null or not an Object` kind of tells us otherwise.

Comment: There is never a `files` property in IE8 (or IE9 and older), as there is no `FileList` since these browsers do not implement the File API.

Comment: I added the fix I ended up using in my initial post. I added .split('\\') so I ended up with only the filename without the path/fakepath

Answer (score 4):

IE9 and older do not support the File API.  As a result, there is no `files` property at all, and multiple-selection of files is not possible.  You only have access to the file name via the `value` property on the file input.

Comment: Okay, Thank you for your answer I guess I'll need to find a fix for this.

Comment: The only "fix" is to use flash or java, neither of which I recommend.